# CSS: How to make this kind layout?

Tags: css

```
|---| |---|
|   | |   |
|---| |   |
      |   |
      |   |
      |   |
      |---|
```

I'll make the left div `float:left`, but then it will display like:

```
|---| |---|
|   | |   |
|---| |   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
|---|
```

The right column will wrap around the float elements. This is not what I wanted.

One possible solution is to use Bootstrap's Grid System. But I want the **left element have its original width**(e.g. a width of a `H1` tag), rather than the width given from the grid like `spanX`

Another solution is to set `margin-left` of the right element, set it to a fixed value. But still, the left elements width should not be a given value, it should be flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enclose both columns within divs and float them both to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Try left section as float:left & right section as float:right. 
May be this will help you out.

```
Example:
.leftSection {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.rightSection {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

or go for this one:

```
<div style="float:left">
  <div style="float:left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div style="float:right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="float:right">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: But I'll have other elements in the right side of these two. So float:right is not a good choice

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="your-problem float-left">
        <div class="tiny-small-floating-left float-left">
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="other-elements-to-right float-right">
    </div>
</div>
```

I just tried to show some floating things. Hope, this will help a bit.